# flex - changing default cursor when executing copy on an item list

Tags: apache-flex, cursor

I am trying to change the default mouse cursor for a list drag and drop.
I was trying to get the COPY cursor using DragMananger and event.preventDefault()- but got a very weird cursor behavior (the items' drop indicator was wrongly presented - etc.) Therefor i am trying to stick to default - this works fine - but my cursor now on copy is a simple arrow, and i would like to get the arrow with the grin plus on it. How can i change the default?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the "Grin Plus"?

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of documentation on creating and using custom cursors with Flex.  [Here is my own blog post](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/2/25/Creating-a-Custom-Cursor-in-Flex) and [podcast](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/2/21/Custom-Flex-Cursors--2182011---Episode-95--Flextras-Friday-Lunch) on the topic.

If you perform a [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Flex%20Custom%20Cursor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), lots more info comes up.

If you need to change the dragImage, you can do so by setting the dragImage property on the [DragManager.doDrag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/DragManager.html#doDrag%28%29) event.  Google also provides a lot of info on [changing the dragImage](http://www.google.com/search?q=Flex%20Custom%20Cursor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=MLM&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&biw=1067&bih=685&source=hp&q=Flex%20DragImage&pbx=1&oq=Flex%20DragImage&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=125064l126957l0l127405l14l8l0l0l0l0l455l2009l2-3.2.1l6&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7acb2c039c8d8b9a).